# Whitespace error with old MySQL code

Tags: mysql, forum

Recently, I've been trying to code a forum from various old tutorials on the internet, However I've recently reached a problem - Although I've done exactly as the tutorial has said, I receive a whitespace error. I presume this may be because some MySQL commands may have changed. If anyone could assist me in telling me what is incorrect and how to fix it, Please do so!

```
   25: $sql = "ìINSERT INTO sections(sect_name, sect_description)
26: VALUES('' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sect_name']) . ì',
27: '' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sect_description']) . ì')'";
28: $result = mysql_query($sql);
```

The error message is:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in [Name of directory] on line 26

Comment: Either the tutorial is completely wrong (it's out of date either way), or you've not done it the same at all.

Comment: Problems I see: 1) some sort of foreign language version of insert, `ìINSERT INTO`, and 2) there may not be a space before `VALUES)

Comment: And the turorial you use, uses super old techniques!!! Get another one

Comment: The problem here is that I can't seem to find any written down up to date tutorials; I'm deaf and thus youtube tutorials are normally significantly more  difficult to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily:

```
 $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO sections(sect_name, sect_description)
    VALUES('%s', '%s');"
 , mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sect_name']) . i
 , mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sect_description']) . i);
```

The '%s' are replaced with the variables from the sprintf function.
That way it's easier to read than concatenating the whole string.